# How to transfer $scope.variables to controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am building a system where i have items listed in a list with variables

1. Title
2. Skills
3. Budget
4. Posted

I also have a Modal that opens up when i click on an item in the list. I would like to take the current selected item and use its variables in my second modal controller? Is this possible?

I was thinking of using a service where i cache all data that is pulled from database, but then i dont know how i would only display selected item and not EVERY item in the modal.

Here is my controller for the list items:

```
app.controller('openProjectsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'projectsModal',
function ($scope, $http, projectsModal) {

  $http.get("http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getProjects.php")
  .success(function (response) {
    $scope.projects = response.projects;
  });

  $scope.showModal = function() {
      projectsModal.deactivate();
      projectsModal.activate();
  };    

}]);
```

Modal Controller(Where i want to view the Selected Variables):

```
app.controller('projectsModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'projectsModal',
function ($scope, $timeout, projectsModal) {

var ctrl = this;

ctrl.closeMe = function () {
  projectsModal.deactivate();
};

}]);
```

Comment: what kind of modal is? Angular-UI?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use variables of one controller inside another controller using two methods

1. Create Service to communicate between them.
2. Use $rootScope.$broadcast

sample code

```
angular.module('myservice', []).service('msgBus', function() {
        this.serviceValue= {};

    }]);
});
```

and use it in controller like this:

controller 1

```
angular.module('myservice', []).controller('ctrl1',function($scope, msgBus) {
    $scope.sendmsg = function() {
        msgBus.serviceValue='Hello'; 
   }
});
```

controller 2

```
angular.module('myservice', []).controller('ctrl2',function($scope, msgBus) {
$scope.checkValue(){   
alert( msgBus.serviceValue);
}
});
```

Comment: Alright i understand the service could be used, but how do you ONLY display data for SELECTED list item. I only know the method cache the results from $http, but thats would then display all the results?

Comment: you can apply ng-model on your <select> then store that model value inside service variable

Comment: Are you able to provide a quick sample for the Service Method?

Comment: check the new edited answer ,I have provided a sample code with it

Comment: How about adding a $scope and not a string?

Comment: its not a good practice ,If you can do it in a angular way why to go for any hack .. :)

Comment: I havent been able to get this to work how i need it. i guess the only option here is to query the DB for the single project each time its selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Html
<div ng-click="listClick()"></div> //this might be list or other.But i take div element here.
//scope
$scope.listClick= function(obj, $event){
    console.log($event.target);
    //Save $event.target element using service and used in next controller.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Angular UI modals you can use this:

```
app.controller('openProjectsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal',
function ($scope, $http, $modal) {

   // Open modal for code
   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'modal.html',
     controller: 'projectsModalCtrl',
     resolve: {
        yourObject: function() {
            return $scope.yourObject;
        }
     },
     scope: $scope
   });
});

app.controller('projectsModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$modalInstance', 'yourObject', 
function ($scope, $timeout, $modalInstance, yourObject) {

   $scope.yourObject = yourObject;

}]);
```

Comment: Unfortunetly i was having issues with using ui Modals so i am not using them anymore, If you can tell me how to use them then i might be able to use them instead.

Comment: In my answer there is everything you need to use them, first inject $modal then open it with $modal.open (probably after a click somewhere), when you open it you can define the controller to be used by it and resolve the scope to be injected into the modal controller. That's it.